# angular-route wont redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem, my page after login is not redirecting to main page. I have checked condition login working when I use `$window.location`. I want to use `angular-route` to prevent user without login to access my main menu. If I use `$window.location`, the user can access my main menu without login. Here is my js file

```
 app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
        templateUrl:'index.html'
      })
      .when('/mainmenu',{
    resolve:{
      "check":function($location,$rootScope){
        if (!$rootScope.loggedIn) {
          $location.path('/');
        }
      }
    },
    templateUrl:'content/mainmenu2.html'
  })      
.otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
      });
    });

    app.controller("logincont", ['$scope','$http','$window','$rootScope','$location',function($scope,$http,$window,$rootScope,$location){
    $scope.login = function () {
           $http.get('http://localhost:8089/MonitoringAPI/webresources/login?a='+$scope.userid+'&d='+$scope.password).then(function(response){
           $scope.reslogin  = response.data;
          if($scope.reslogin == null)
            {
              alert('Login Incorrect'); 
            }
            else
            {
              $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
              $location.path('/mainmenu');

            }
      });
          };   

          }]);
```

here is my html

```
<form>
        <h1 class="tengah"> Form Login </h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputId">User Id</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userid" placeholder="userid" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="pass" placeholder="Password" required>{{password}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()">
            <span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span>Login</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a flag `allowUnauth` on the routes those you don't want to authenticate for e.g `login` and then change your routing like:-

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
        templateUrl:'index.html',
        allowUnauth:true
      })
      .when('/mainmenu',{
    templateUrl:'content/mainmenu2.html'
  }).otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
      });
    });

 var unauthRoutes= [];
    angular.forEach($route.routes, function(route, path) {
        // push route onto unauthRoutes if it has a truthy allowUnauth value
        route.allowUnauth && (unauthRoutes.push(path));
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, nextLoc, currentLoc) 
    {
        var atuhRoute= (-1 === unauthRoutes.indexOf($location.path()));
        if(atuhRoute && !$rootScope.loggedIn) {
            $location.path('/');
        }
    });
```

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2W3LdDjdxUdvuezvhGCy?p=preview)

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha check this out https://plnkr.co/edit/2W3LdDjdxUdvuezvhGCy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
"use strict";

configureApp.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
function configureApp($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/mainmenu', {
      resolve: {
        ensureAthenticated: (function() {
          ensureAthenticated.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
          function ensureAthenticated($rootScope) {
            if(!$rootScope.loggedIn) {
              return Promise.reject('not athenticated');
            }
            else return Promise.resolve();
          };
          return ensureAthenticated;
        }())
      },
      templateUrl:'content/mainmenu2.html'
    })
    .otherwise('/');
}

app.config(configureApp);
```

Comment: can you give plunk @Aluan Haddad